# код работает не правильно

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, случайные-числа

```
if textOfEasyHardLabel == "Hard" {
                //for hard level code
                if coins.count == 20 || coins.count == 16 || coins.count == 12 || coins.count == 8 || coins.count == 4 {
                    let numberToDelete = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))
                    for _ in 0..<numberToDelete {
                        let tag = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(coins.count)))
                        coins[tag].hidden = true
                        coins.removeAtIndex(tag)
                        count -= [tag].count
                    }
                }
           }
```

Код работает некорректно. coins.tag всегда исчезает не рандомное количество, а 4, хотя условием задано от 1 до 3-х! В связи с чем может быть такой баг? 
Может будут идеи...

Comment: а что такое `count -= [tag].count`?

Comment: Есть переменная  - count, равная количеству объектов на экране, т.е. 21. Это мне для контроля при тестовых испытаниях.

Comment: эта строчка у меня вообще отказалась компилироваться. но если она у вас и работает, то видимо создает массив с одним элементом и возвращает этот самый 1 через каунт. пробовали брейкпоинт поставить и посмотреть какая строка делает не то, что от нее одидается

Comment: !!! Нет не делал. Точно. (Я в программировании новичок). Попробую. Спасибо.